# DLL error in Edge.js when called from C#

Tags: c#, node.js, edgejs

First I've installed the latest [Edge Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Edge.js/). Then I'm running the basic hello world starting example and have been running into this error on Windows 2010 w/ Visual Studio 2015.

[image]

When I execute the same hello world code on OS-X I get this error.

[image]

Here's a break out of the locals variable tree. Looks like the error might be similar.

[image]

The code looks like this. It is literally copied from the [README.md of the repo](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge#how-to-nodejs-hello-world).

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using EdgeJs;

class Program
{
    public static async void Start()
    {
        var func = Edge.Func(@"
            return function (data, callback) {
                callback(null, 'Node.js welcomes ' + data);
            }
        ");

        Console.WriteLine(await func(".NET"));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run((Action)Start).Wait();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this problem by copying the folder *edge* into the bin folder.

Reference: https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge/issues/565#issuecomment-315343743

Answer (score 0):

When you install Edgejs from nuget it creates an edge folder in your solution. Node.dll should be in your x64 & x86 folders.

Comment: Are you saying it might not be there? Not sure what course of action to take.  :-(

Comment: try to reinstall the package or build it yourself from their github page.